# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: php, php7

Tengo este código PHP:

```
<?php
$gasto = "$75 de llaves<br />
$20 motores<br />
$200 mano de obra";

$enlace = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComentarios(\''.$gasto.'\');">'.$gasto.'</a>';

print $enlace;
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getComentarios(comentarios)
{
    $(".comentarios").html(comentarios);
    $(".comentario").show();
}
```

Estoy tratando de pasar una variable de tipo cadena a una función javascript, cuando el valor de esa variable no contiene caracteres especiales todo funciona de maravilla pero cuando contiene caracteres especiales como en este caso me tira el siguiente error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Que hace tu función getComentario, trata de dar los detalles para poder decirte en donde está el problema. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que pueda ser de ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder imprimir `HTML` multi-línea es necesario utilizar `` ` `` **backtick** dentro del a función `getComentarios()`, es por eso que cuando haces un string pequeño o que no tiene caracteres `HTML` por eso no te da error.

Por lo tanto tu código quedaría así:

```
<?php
$gasto = "$75 de llaves<br />
$20 motores<br />
$200 mano de obra";

$enlace = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="getComentarios(`' . $gasto . '`)">' . $gasto . '</a>';

print $enlace;
?>
```